# Software Engineer & Product Management Role

Tags: career-development, promotion, title

What would be a reasonable job title for someone who spends 70% of their time software engineering  and the other 30% doing product management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all the places I've worked, this role split typically describes your average *Senior Software Engineer*, *Development Manager*, or a suitable amalgamation of those.

Once upon a time I had a role with about that same split, and I was the *Systems Development Manager*.